# Nodejs module for mysql - Connections in pool not showing in status

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I want to use mySQL nodeJs connection pooling in the felixge Node module.
It appears to work fine except that I am not sure how to find if its really working, as intended. The pool connection params, passed to mysql.createPool() are:

```
  dbConnectionParams = {
                  connectionLimit: 20,
                  host: 'localhost',
                  user:   'jdoe',
                  password:'somepasswd',
                  database: 'myDB'
  };
```

All queries using connections from the pool work fine. However, when I try to see the actual connections using "show processlist" I see about 4 to 8 connections at any time, never 20. Should these not be listed too? Is there any other mySQL statement to see them or are they not opened until we actually need them? If so, is there any way to force open them so that later, when the connection is actually needed, there is no time lost in opening them?

I have read the documentation which states that "connections are lazily created by the pool." I thought that the whole idea of pooling is to circumvent this so they are not opened on an as-needed (lazy?) basis but are pre-opened.

UPDATE: Here is the output. Am trying to co-relate it to connectionLimit  parameter upon new requests coming in.

```
+----+------+-----------------+------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| Id | User | Host            | db   | Command | Time | State | Info                 |
+----+------+-----------------+-------------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| 38 | jdoe | localhost:50716 | myDB | Sleep   |  669 |       | NULL             |
| 39 | jdoe | localhost       | myDB | Query   |    0 | NULL  | show processlist |
| 41 | jdoe | localhost:50718 | myDB | Sleep   |    4 |       | NULL             |
| 44 | jdoe | localhost:50721 | myDB | Sleep   |    4 |       | NULL             |
| 45 | jdoe | localhost:50722 | myDB | Sleep   |    4 |       | NULL             |
| 46 | jdoe | localhost:50723 | myDB | Sleep   |    5 |       | NULL             |
| 47 | jdoe | localhost:50724 | myDB | Sleep   |    4 |       | NULL             |
| 48 | jdoe | localhost:50725 | myDB | Sleep   |    4 |       | NULL             |
```

+----+------+-----------------+-------------+---------+------+-------+------------------+

Comment: Do you have specific performance issues with the pool connections _not_ being opened at the start of your app? From what you're saying, your app never performs more than 4 to 8 concurrent queries, so having 20 open connections might be considered a waste of resources.

Comment: @robertklep In testing mode, which is what I am in now, I do not expect 20 open connections. In production, yes.  In any event, I am trying to co-relate the output of show processlist to the pool connection parameter while some processing is going on - even trying to put scripts into intermediate loops to prolong the exit so that the connection is held long enough to be reflected in the output. Please see UPDATE.

Comment: My guess is that your queries are relatively short-lived, so there's no need for the pool to open more than the amount of open connections you witness. Once a connection has been opened, I would expect it to stay open (and show up in the connection list).

Comment: @robertklep I think I just need to do some more experimentation to get a hang of   how many connections open at start,  what if 20 come at one time and only four thereafter (does it keep all 20 open?),  impact of exceeding pool limits, etc.  Documentation does not address the multiple issues associated with db connection pooling.